# How can I make C++ function calls from an R package as fast as the sourceCpp function?

Tags: c++, r, optimization, rcpp, montecarlo

I am working on a project that uses a Monte Carlo simulation to calculate thousands of values from a complex equation. When I implemented this equation in R, it took minutes to run. This was fixed by implementing it in C++ and using Rcpp to port it to my project - it now takes about 15 seconds with the `sourceCpp()` command from Rcpp. Note that the loop for the Monte Carlo simulation is still implemented in R; it looks something like this:

```
sourceCpp("myCppFile.cpp")  # sources int myCppFunc(int i) from myCppFile.cpp

vals = c()
while(length(vals) < 1000) {
    new_val = myCppFunc(i)
    if(new_val > 10) {
        vals = append(vals, new_val)
    }
}
```

This takes about 15 seconds. However, when I turned this into a full package as suggested, it takes around 20 seconds. This doesn't seem like a lot, but the extra time adds up.

Why does it take longer to call from a package than it does when using `sourceCpp()` and is there anyway I can make the calls from the package faster? Would implementing the Monte Carlo loop in C++ significantly help with the speed?

Comment: Please see about a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- right now we have _nothing_ to go by about your claim 'but a package is five seconds worse that sourcing a file'.